# Cambiar variable desde el boton de una notificacion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-notifications

Este es el método que muestra las notificaciones,lo que quiero es que cuando se le de a uno de los dos botones de la notificación cambie uno de las variables globales de la clase en la que dicho método esta,es decir al dale a uno de sus dos botones que un int pase por ejemplo de 0 a 1

```
 public void showNotification() {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setAutoCancel(false)


            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view, "View details", contentIntent)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view, "View details", contentIntent)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)



            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification );
}
```

Comment: donde esta el evento ?

Comment: Que variable global? considera agregar más información.

Comment: imaginad que ese método esta dentro de una clase ,en esa clase hay un entero que se llama permiso ,mi intención es cambiarlo a 0 cuando le doy a un botón de la notificación y a 1 cuando le doy a otro